# Why is Rust ok with accepting a different struct when implementing the same trait?

Tags: rust

I have the following in my tests which compiles and works well:

```
#[test]
fn zoo_test() {
    let mut zoo = Zoo::new();

    zoo.add(Monkey::new("m1".to_string()));
    zoo.add(Limur::new("l1".to_string()));

    assert_eq!(zoo.hi_all::<Monkey>(), vec![
        "Monkey m1 says: ah ah ah".to_string(),
        "Limur l1 says: yo".to_string()
    ]);
}
```

However, I'm a bit confused why `zoo.hi_all::<Monkey>()` works since it could be **either monkey or limur**. In other words I don't understand why it works for limur, or am I doing this wrong?

**Edit:** Here's the code I'm using for `src/zoo.rs`:

```
pub mod animal;
pub mod monkey;
pub mod limur;

use std::collections::VecDeque;
use animal::Animal;

pub struct Zoo<'a> {
    list: VecDeque<Box<dyn Animal + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Zoo<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Zoo<'a> {
        Zoo {
            list: VecDeque::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add<T>(&mut self, animal: T)
    where
        T: Animal + 'a,
    {
        self.list.push_back(Box::new(animal));
    }

    pub fn hi_all<T>(&self) -> Vec<String>
    where
        T: Animal + 'a,
    {
        let mut hi: Vec<String> = vec![];
        for animal in &self.list {
            if let Some(what) = animal.says() {
                hi.push(what);
            }
        }
        hi
    }
}
```

Comment: You should share the code for `Zoo::hi_all` and probably all the code for `Zoo`. As it is, your code isn't a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it's hard to explain its behavior. In particular, it's not clear how `Zoo::hi_all` uses its type parameter which is the crux of the issue.

Comment: Hi @SCappella, thank you for taking the time! I've updated the question with impl of Zoo.

Comment: You use a generic type parameter `T : Animal` never bound to any variable. Rust does (astonishingly) not complain about unused type parameters. Just remove `T` from the signature of `hi_all`, it makes no difference.

Comment: Ookay, mind blown. Thank you @CoronA. I have so many questions though: I guess it makes sense that `add()` actually accepts an `animal`, so I need `T` there but 1) why doesn't rust warn me to get rid of it on `hi_all()` and more importantly 2) why does the original `hi_all::<Monkey>()` work?!

Comment: I do not know why rust does not warn in this case (1). Yet why should your code fail (2)? `Monkey` has the `trait Animal?  and the lifetime `'a` so the type checker is pleased. And it is hard to prove that there could not be any meaningful use of `T` in future implementations.

Comment: The generic parameter `T` in `hi_all<T>` is never used

Comment: Thank you @CoronA and Svetlin Zarev, I think that makes sense now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type variable `T` is declared in the type of this function:

```
pub fn hi_all<T>(&self) -> Vec<String>
where
    T: Animal + 'a,
{
    let mut hi: Vec<String> = vec![];
    for animal in &self.list {
        if let Some(what) = animal.says() {
            hi.push(what);
        }
    }
    hi
}
```

but is never actually used in the function's body! Removing that constraint will have no impact because there is no variable of type `T` mentioned in the function.

In fact, it never *could* be used in any practical way, because the elements of the `VecDeque` are of a specific concrete type, `Box<dyn Animal>` whereas, from the perspective of code inside the function, `T` could be *any* type that implements `Animal`.

If you need to filter the animals *by type* then I suggest you use an enum instead of trait objects, so you can discriminate on the enum variant.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Hall, makes sense!